# How long can long polling using XHR hold a connection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

I'm using XHR long polling to simulate communication between clients, but I was wondering, how long can I keep a connection without responding? Is this based on the timeout of TCP?

Thanks in advance!